# What is the (craziest, stupidest, silliest) thing a client/boss asked you to do?

Tags: management, client-relations

See title, but I am asking from a technical perspective, not

> Take my 40 year old virgin niece on a date or you're fired.

Comment: If she's a 40 year old virgin, she's probably also an employee. Wouldn't that be against policy?

Comment: can you return her unopened next morning?

Comment: Go read http://clientsfromhell.net/

Comment: @Pierre-Alain I've read quite a bit of that site...good stuff.

Comment: This whole Q+As is like Dilbert, but in real life.

Comment: @Agos or office space.  Either one applies to everywhere I have worked, large, small, big-business to engineering centric, new, old...and everywhere in between :)

Comment: @BioBuckyBall: Which guidelines of the big 6 do you think this question apply? Gradually we will close questions that doesn't fit on the 6 Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions. If you think your question doesn't meet enough points it would be a good thing the author of the question initiate the close process. Otherwise community or moderators can take the initiative if they they consider this question inappropriate to this site. Thank you. See more: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: @bigown Because it's the only question on prgrammers that Joel answered?  Seriously, this is the kind of question I thought programmers was for.  Close it if you want, I'm done.

Comment: @BioBuckyBall: Do you read what I wrote? Do you read every word?

Comment: @bigown Yep, and the linked blog post.  And it doesn't meet those guidelines in my opinion, so should be closed.  But I still think it's an interesting question about programming.

Comment: @Tim What policy prevents an employee from dating another ? o.O

Comment: Ah, the mods strike again against clear community interest (70 up-votes!). Sigh. You know, maybe if so many very popular questions are against rules, maybe rules need changing?

Comment: My answer: I once worked at a company where they built a web site engine using file system storage because one of the directors did not want to install a Database on his laptop. His laptop was never used for serving sites, just the occasional demo. So we actually had 4 programmers spending god knows how long on a file-storage based system.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

To market Neal Stephenson's sci-fi thriller Snow Crash, I was asked to write a "benign" computer virus. It would "benignly" pretend to take over the user's computer and replace the screen with snow, a.k.a., a "snow crash." After a minute or so of snow, the snow would fade out and be replaced by an advertisement for the book. This would be "benign," you see. The virus would spread through normal means, but nobody would mind because after taking over their computer "you'd just get a fun ad and then be relieved that nothing bad happened to your computer."

I was actually told to do this at a major worldwide corporation. I had to write a memo explaining all the laws this would break and all 17 bad things that could happen if they really made me implement this.

Comment: You were told to do this at Viacom ???

Comment: Yikes! <15 chars>

Comment: Holy balls.  That's the most perfect example of the "It's only evil if other people do it -- if WE do it it MUST be all right!" mindset I've heard in a while.

Comment: Meh. It wouldn't have been any worse than the book itself... ;)

Comment: That's awesome. We can sell it in a bundle with my 'benign' keylogger that serves up ads when users visit competitors sites, and we'll be rich.

Comment: Do you mean Neal Stephenson's Snow Crash?

Comment: I wonder what Neal thought of that?

Comment: This would actually have been a really fun project.  I would have done it and then told them about the laws.

Comment: @Neil G: 1. have something blatantly illegal done for you 2. profit! 3. blame employee when you get caught 4. more profit!!! (this worked for the Sony rootkit, IIRC)

Comment: There aren't words for how pissed I'd be if someone did that to my computer.

Comment: I was asked to do a similar thing - install a new screensaver with adverts for all visitors to a website.

Comment: "fun ad!" - sigh

Comment: I'm curious to know what the 17 bad things would be.

Comment: Whew... well I'm glad they listened to reason. (I can't believe it's a year and a half later and nobody else said that)

Answer (score 135):

"This DLL you wrote is only 17kb. Can you add some code to make it bigger?  The client is paying us a lot of money, and we want them to get their money's worth."

Comment: Easiest profit maximizing strategy ever.

Comment: 1) Embed a flight simulator easter egg. 2) ... 3) Profit!

Comment: Did you work for Oracle?

Comment: That is at least a reason that makes (business) sense.

Comment: It is the same strategy people used in selling computer games: they make the box that contains the CD big and heavy so that parents can think they are getting their money's worth.

Comment: HP printer drivers MUST do this. They're the only company who seems to think that 400 MB installs are normal for simple printers. Now, what key combination starts the flight sim?

Comment: Omg, I was told the same thing too once, that's scary :D

Comment: You call that crazy/stupid/silly? One client was doing this on a regular basis, because *their* customer was measuring progress by the size of the release files they got.

Comment: I guess he works for MS ;)

Comment: One of my all time favourite answers, anywhere, ever.

Answer (score 95):

Use Visual SourceSafe.

Comment: Nothing tops this.

Comment: Beats having nothing.

Comment: @Rob - I'm not so sure.  Having nothing, at least you *know* your source is "unprotected".  VSS gives the *illusion* of protection whilst actually making things worse.  It's a false sense of security of the worst kind.

Comment: I'm with Rob. It does beat having nothing. Although I no longer use it. Over my career, I've probably used it for a decade in total and never had any major data loss. @CraigTP, it may be unreliable, but it isn't 100% unreliable as you seem to be implying. A VSS installation that is backed up frequently (and a long tail of backups are kept) is indeed better than nothing.

Comment: Er.. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/19085/have-you-ever-been-really-badly-burned-by-vss

Comment: Sure, VSS sucks; but if that's the craziest/stupidest/silliest thing a boss/client has ever asked you to do, you have absolutely nothing to complain about.

Answer (score 86):

"You know this enormous 20-year-old Cobol program that contains piles and piles of hard-coded business rules that more or less defines our company? Would you mind converting it to .NET?"

Yikes.

We go live in a few weeks.

Wish me luck..

Comment: Jeez, +1 just for sympathy!

Comment: Do you have a Paypal donate button somewhere? I'd like to buy you some aspirin.

Comment: Ha!  I've been there, except it was converting to an awful, open-source Java crapball.  Good times (I almost left software after that one).

Comment: Must say though, it's been a lot of fun actually making it work. And the end result isn't *that* bad.

Comment: reminds me of this depressing poster: http://yfrog.com/0q21bmj

Comment: If you accomplish it you'll be a programming God, and also lucky to get a "thanks"

Comment: You have just described the project we (finally) just finished. It was supposed to take a year and a half but went a year over and roughly doubled the budget.

Comment: Isn't there a company that made a IL compiler for the COBOL language?

Comment: Thank you for your support everyone. And just to let you know, we are now live!

Comment: That's nothing! I once had to incorporate the business logic of *three separate* old, heavily modified Cobol programs into a single C++ DLL.

Comment: The worst part of this is that if you do it really really well, you'll get almost no credit. "Yup, it works exactly the same as it did before."

Answer (score 78):

My brother and I were working on a multimedia heavy-website for a very [famous rock star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_%28musician%29) many years ago.

When the client saw the site he noticed some compression artifacts on some of the JPEGs and asked what was wrong with them. We explained that images need compression for bandwidth purposes and that the images were currently compressed at about 80% quality. He was offended and said something to the effect of

> I haven't gotten to where I am today
>   by doing things at 80%, set it to
>   100%.

We tried to explain how it would affect users, but he would have none of it. It resulted in the slowest "virtual world" website ever. ***This actually happened***.

Comment: "All these computers and digital gadgets are no good, they just fill your head with numbers and that can't be good for you." - http://www.boston.com/ae/specials/culturedesk/2010/07/prince_the_internet_is_over.html

Comment: I laughed hard when I first read that article.

Comment: At least he didn't ask you to turn it up to 110%.

Comment: If it really was Prince you were working for, you might want to listen to him.  There are very, very few people who can walk into a recording studio, alone, with nothing but a concept, and walk out with a complete master tape for an album that will likely go platinum.

Comment: John. It really was him. Trust me, if I wanted to dress fancy or play the electric guitar like a wizard, he would be the first person I would go to. But not for web design best practices.

Comment: At first I was reading it as wanting 100% compression, not 100% image quality!

Comment: @Andrew, Good point. I have edited for clarification

Comment: "I haven't gotten to where I am today by doing things at 80%, set it to 100%." That's actually an AWESOME quote. The person who said it is Prince right? not some manager or something?

Comment: It was actually him.

Comment: I had an associate at work who loved to use similar expressions.  Me: "We can't make that happen for these good technical reasons". Him: "It's not about how it works on the insides, it's about how the user feels."

Answer (score 72):

> We need to delay the site launch by
>   two weeks because Mercury is in
>   retrograde and it's a bad time to
>   start new things.

Comment: At least they didn't want to launch 2 weeks early.

Comment: Ha! I have heard that one a lot in India

Comment: ha ha ha ... this is one of the coolest thing I have ever seen .. +1 to Gsto and Jeff.

Comment: If you were writing software for a space probe, this might make sense.

Comment: This is how I read it... "We need to delay the site launch by two weeks because Mercurial is in retrograde and it's a bad time to start new things."

Comment: Mercurial is always in retrograde.

Answer (score 70):

Obviously after reading some business magazine on an airplane about how XML was the hot new technology (this was circa 2002), one of our executives asked me if our application used XML, when I said no he asked me if we could add it.

Now, I'm not talking about a feature to import/export files in XML format, he simply wanted it to be part of the architecture for no reason other than it was popular at the moment and would lend credibility to our app.

Comment: I had the same thing in 1998 - except the article was on Oracle, and our app was essentially a workflow diagram editor.  We ported the file format we were outputting from disk to a table and took a dependency on Oracle licenses.  Made version control very difficult as well.

Comment: Oh boy.  I had the exact same thing (at around the same time) and it was also regarding XML.  What was it about XML that made the execs start drooling?

Comment: That's pretty common.  It's called "buzzword compliance".

Comment: That was 2002.  Nowadays the executives laugh at you and call you a hippie if you don't use XML.

Comment: Managers that insist on XML without knowing why often use the office Internet connection to 'questionable ends'. I'm just sayin ...

Comment: @CraigTP I think it's the 'X'. It's dramatic and appealing.

Comment: Looking back I should have just appeased by saying. Even better, our web app uses HTML which has a whole extra letter in the acronym and the code is like a specialized version of XML that meets our exact business need!

Comment: And now here I am, wondering why TF I have to root through four XML config files to figure out how a combination of Struts, Struts-Tiles, JSP and Spring are coming together to build a single HTML page.

Comment: So that's what happened the the Spring framework?

Answer (score 68):

"Right now, the usernames are required to be unique, and the passwords are not. Could we make it the other way around?"

Comment: ha.. I made the mistake once where both the username and password needed to be unique.  short lived mistake thankfully

Comment: What the heck were they trying to accomplish?

Comment: As I recall it was something to do with a client sharing email addresses at a company. Emails and usernames were 1:1, so the idea was to create multiple accounts with the same username and use the passwords to differentiate them.

Comment: In that case, they might as well drop the usernames entirely and look up the account based on the (unique!) password. Sheesh... did they tell you anything else about why they wanted it that way?

Comment: No, but they didn't need to; it was obviously faulty logic. They got talked out if it quick enough.

Comment: @Craig Walker Amazon used to have this. I created one account with my yahoo email address, and then another account using a different password with the same email address. I don't know when they fixed this, but depending on the password I used, I'd get a different account.

Answer (score 65):

About 7 years ago I worked at a bespoke software shop that decided to sell one of its products.  It was an end-to-end operations suite for some industry.  Well, this industry wasn't known for being super technological, so somehow we ended up providing third-party technical support for their servers and IT infrastructure instead of farming it out to independent small business IT consultants.

One day, a customer's server encountered disk corruption.  The server we had sold them was configured with an Adaptec RAID controller, set up for a RAID 1 mirror.  Their application database was toast.  They hadn't performed backups in months.  The backups they had performed were unusable.  They ended up losing 8 months of data.  They hired an IT consultant to handle this investigative work.

Phone calls ensued, and the sales manager (known for promising impossible features) apparently told them it would be taken care of, and wrote it up in a contract.

The sales manager promised the customer that we would ensure that the application database and any other application-related files would never be replicated by RAID controllers if the files were considered to be corrupt.  No configuration should be necessary either.  Yep.  We were told to deliver this functionality in 2 weeks, or the customer would fire us.

So the program manager -- who had some large enterprise CRM products, and other serious development successes, under his belt -- and I had a meeting with the COO, and the sales manager.  The program manager was detailing how insane, impossible, and insanely impossible this was.  The sales manager (military background) would simply scream in his face (literally!), "I don't care!  How hard can it be to make the RAID thing not RAID?!  Their data would be fine on the other drive if the RAID thing hadn't screwed it up!"

At the end of that meeting, the program manager quit with a zero-day notice.  So I was now tasked with this.  Over the next week, I petitioned both Adaptec and LSI Logic to provide an engineer for a conference call, simply to laugh in the face of the sales manager.

Ultimately, they obliged, and held up their end of the bargain.  And they went into detail how ridiculously unfeasible it was.  The guy from LSI was particularly harsh - he didn't sugar coat anything.

I didn't have to implement the feature.  One I did have to implement was a custom security scheme requested by a customer, that would allow them to toggle any of the application's controls - on a control by control basis - as visible, disabled, enabled, read-only, or read-write.  In theory, there were 146,000 combinations.  And if you accidentally screwed up by say... disabling a control group, you'd have inadvertent side effects.  Needless to say, when I was given the ultimatum that it had to be implemented, I also quit with a zero-day notice.

Comment: `+1` for "quit with zero-day notice", because sometimes you just have to leave, and some people never get that and keep muddling on.

Answer (score 58):

They asked me to search a Commercial Product that could find and fix source code bugs automagically.
Still searching..since 2001 :).

Comment: Why can't you use an open source product to do this task? Do they just love spending money? After all, it'll be expensive! :)

Comment: "Could we have a list of all the unexpected errors, please..."

Comment: Imagine if a client doesn't need a developer to develop his application. He himself can write anything and debugger will solve it automagically. Let me google it, Ill let u know if I find anything like this :-)

Comment: Familiar with Mutivac?  http://www.multivax.com/last_question.html

Comment: I actually have such a tool. The problem is that it takes several weeks or months depending on the problem at hand, tremendous amounts of interaction with your team, lots of coffee, and is very expensive.

Comment: @Michael send me two copies please, I need to getting job done.

Comment: @Thor thanks for the Multivac link, really enjoyed it.

Answer (score 57):

I once had a client specification that literally called for code capable of traveling backwards in time.

My employer harvested data for the client, and we were to deliver it in file format X at ten-minute intervals between 9 AM and 5 PM, save for the final delivery, which was in format Y (just X with a different footer).  I did just that ... and they freaked.  We were collecting low-volume data, and really only had one or two data points to deliver on any given day.

"QUIT SPAMMING US WITH EMPTY FILES!!!" they cried.  "FIVE K'S EVERY TEN MINUTES ENCLOGULATES OUR BANDTUBES!"

Okay.  So, my code checked every ten minutes, and only delivered if there was anything to deliver.  Fair enough.

"BUT THE LAST FILE MUST BE IN FORMAT Y!!!" they screamed.  "MODERN TECHNOLOGY CONFUSES AND ANGERS US!  FIX IT OR WE WILL BEAT YOU WITH A MASTODON FEMUR!*"

(* -- It is possible I'm misremembering portions of the conversation.)

"So, I'm only to deliver the file if there's fresh data to deliver."

"YES."

"And the final delivery for the day is supposed to be a different file format."

"YES."

"Except I have no way of knowing which file will be the last of the day until the end of the day."

"YES."

"So the only way for me to implement this is to write code that goes backwards in time at the end of the day to redo the format on what turned out to be the final delivery."

"COULD YOU HAVE IT REPORT SPORTS SCORES?  WE SAW BACK TO THE FUTURE II.  BIFF TANNEN MAKES US HAPPY."

I refused, in part because violating causality is an unethical programming practice, in part because CPAN.org didn't have a module that would let me do it.  (I checked.)  In the end, they allowed me to send a file in format Y at the end of the day, regardless of whether or not it had any actual data.  I'm pretty sure their bandwidth survived the hit.

Comment: `+1` for "violating causality is an unethical programming practice". Now there's a rule that needs more attention.

Comment: And you didn't consider sending a file every day at 11:59:59 in format Y containing "This is the last file of the day"?

Comment: @DJClayworth: You mean, send a file containing garbage data, rather than the file containing no data, as described in the final paragraph?  Can't say that I did, no.

Comment: This reads like The Oatmeal.

Comment: You could've withheld the last piece of data for each delivery to roll it over to the next one. This way at the end of the day you will always have at least one piece to send in format Y. :)

Comment: My guess is that the file in format Y was supposed to contain all the data collected that day.  But what do I know, I'm just a snail.

Comment: This is one of the funniest answers I've ever read. It should indeed be an Oatmeal comic.

Comment: @Joey Adams: On the internet, nobody knows you're a snail.

Answer (score 52):

Without any discernable cause, I was brought into a private meeting, and told not to check if my computer was being monitored - including, never ever checking my task manager for any reason. I asked if they were monitoring my computer, and was told (roughly) "this is just a preventative thing -- you know, our lawyer told us to tell the employees about this -- but you know, we can't really say -- but I'm not monitoring it now."

(nudge, I think they were monitoring my computer, just not while they were telling me not to look for any monitoring programs. In fact, a few weeks later, I came in early and literally watched the mouse moving around my screen as if by remote -- so I looked through the window of the CEO and saw him remotely clicking around on my computer from his laptop.)

Comment: I hope you don't still work there.

Comment: Sounds like a winner of a company... If you're still there, I'd say bolt.

Comment: What he wants to do ??? Let him code for you ...

Comment: 1) Open up notepad 2) Type "hi boss" 3) ... 4) Profit! Also, a good surveillance program would hide itself from Task Manager.

Comment: Sounds illegal. I hope you got a lawyer.

Answer (score 50):

I once had a long "discussion" with a [pointy-haired boss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-haired_Boss) who insisted that we could store a 2 in a bit datatype because it was "only one digit."

Comment: You can definitely do this. As long as the variable is named "IsATwo"

Comment: just map null to 2!

Comment: bool true,false,file_not_found  (apologies to DailyWTF)

Answer (score 47):

The stupidest thing I've been asked to do is probably a ***ground up rewrite*** of a very large project. It was about 350k lines, all C (with a little perl mixed in for 'helper' scripts) and worked well no matter what clients did to it.

Almost a year later, we had:

- Lots of functions that basically did the same thing as the old functions
- No real improvements in speed or functionality
- A slightly smaller memory footprint
- A much larger executable
- Annoyed clients

Basically, we accomplished nothing that sensible refactoring could not have accomplished. But my boss was happy, we got rid of the helper scripts.

I consider it to be the most egregious waste of time and existing code that I've ever seen.

Comment: It's a little dated but from the StackExchange leader: http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Comment: Also in this you have learned alot ... to not repeat this kind of project in future

Comment: Did they also say _why_ they wanted the rewrite?

Answer (score 46):

*Client:* We've been using your database software for a couple of years, developing our own applications with it, and calling you from time to time for help.

*Me:* Yes, we appreciate doing business with you.

*Client:* Yeah.  Every time we call, you tell us how to use a new feature, or you help us debug our usage, or provide a workaround for some issue.

*Me:*  Sure, we're always happy to be of assistance.

*Client:* Occasionally, your product has an actual bug in it, and your company fixes it and gives us a software update.

*Me:*  We do our best.

*Client:*  Well, what we need from you now is some assurance that **we won't have any more issues.**

*Me:* . . .

Comment: My face twitched a little while reading this.

Comment: @Daenyth, I got that too!

Comment: This is a true story.  The client above was a manager at an company who developed air-traffic control software for logging flight data.  The sole developer on the project (who had no one reviewing his code) called to report a "bug" frequently, but it turned out to be an error on his part 9 out of 10 times.  He didn't know about his own errors because he refused to check error statuses returned by our API.  Why? Because he said any error must indicate a bug, and our library should have no bugs.

Comment: @Bill, sounds like you library should fail badly and loudly including the last 10 error codes returned to calling code.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: It was a C API, so there were no exceptions.  Just return values.  Since the client programmer refused to check return values, there was not much we could do.

Comment: @Bill, perhaps some internal logging for forensic analysis then?

Comment: @Thorbjørn:  Good idea, that would allow us to log most of the client's mistakes, but it wouldn't meet their goal of "we won't have any more issues."  Anyway, this anecdote is from the 1990's.  I earnestly hope that the developer who refused to check return status from our API is now working in a different career.

Comment: I don't get this, seems perfectly normal - the software has been shown to have bugs, the client wants assurances it won't have any more. Seems pretty reasonable. What am I missing ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Some of the client's "issues" were cases where they wanted the software to do something it was not designed to do, or when they made fat-finger mistakes (like misspelling SQL keywords).  They reported these cases as "bugs".

Answer (score 42):

I have been asked to write in a presentation of our software to a major multinational potential customer that we used "spaghetti code" coding technique.

Of course, we're in Italy... sounds good.

Comment: Just so long as the spaghetti is made fresh... right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code#Ravioli_code

Answer (score 36):

**Do some work for free.**

Comment: I've been asked that too.  "We've run out of funding, can you work unpaid for a couple weeks until we get some customers?"

Comment: **There is no free lunch**

Answer (score 35):

Changing my syntax highlighting colors to match the ones used in the version control system.

Comment: haha, a sadist boss/client

Comment: We so had this... and a requirement that EVERY LINE be commented, in the 79th column, so that the code was down the left and comments on the right.  And all of this was enforced by an IDE add-in.

Answer (score 30):

Let's see:

Write programs in C++

1. without the use of version control,
2. no refactoring,
3. no Boost,
4. limited STL (I argued and won on this one),
5. use unverified subcontractor libraries,
6. without a memory profiler (to help fix subcontractor work),
7. no unit testing,
8. stick to 3 letter names for member function names,
9. no test environment (VM not allowed either) just push to production

Comment: Wow. What's your company score on the Joel Test?

Comment: When I first started, 2, I think.  Now that I've been there a while I can say group A: 4 and group B: 8.  Guess which one I'm trying to join and guess which one won't let me.

Comment: Clearly, your boss was of the opinion that 'Real' programmers program with a magnetized needle and a steady hand. ;)

Comment: @brice Don't make me bust out the butterflies...

Comment: No one can ever force you to work without version control. Use whatever you want (I'm an increasingly big fan of git, personally) on your own machine, and gradually other developers will follow along. Hopefully.

Comment: Well, could do 1-4, and 6-9 just for the sportive aspect - but wouldn't agree on #5 then. If you are sent to No Mans Land on a suicide mission, you at least have to have reliable tools.

Comment: Apart from #8, sounds _very_ a job I took in 2004, I didn't last the 6 month probationary period, I walked long before then

Answer (score 30):

Can you take this 10-page report that I asked you to prepare as a word document and make it into a powerpoint presentation because I am really a visual thinker and won't actually read the written report I asked you to make?

Comment: may be this is a way of ensuring that you are doing genuine work and all the important aspects are covered in all the steps and finally the most concise lucid idea is conveyed in the end.

Comment: Quit job, if he say "Do it by E.O.D."

Answer (score 26):

Ok, I want you to scan this picture of a house, when I come back, you should be able to show me the back portion of it.

Comment: ZOOM...ENHANCE!

Comment: oh CSI how I hate you

Comment: Enhance... enhance... enhance... OH JUST PRINT THE DAMN THING!

Comment: @WalterJ89 maybe that's where he got the idea

Comment: BladeRunner comes to mind too.  I seem to recall a scene of enhancing being able to look around a corner...

Comment: Was there an address? I would have run out and taken a picture of the back of the house and showed it to him. Then explain how you have the ability to walk into a photo as if it were another dimension. The print your resume in case he doesn't laugh.

Comment: Isn't the back side of the photo how the hose looks like?

Answer (score 22):

"I don't like the way this Oracle database works.  Why don't we just write our own database?"

(Admittedly, this was over 15 years ago, but still!)

Comment: Well, why not? Some people actually did this, and that's how we got OODBMS. Imagine Amazon or Google using Oracle as DB backend... and then think about what impact speed has on their business.

Answer (score 20):

I was asked to load articles from a competitor's website inside an iframe that would be inside our website's skin, making it look like it came from us.

Comment: Yes ! The same thing happened to me when I was in the training and I was asked to copy contents from various website and paste it into ours and make it look like the original article. I can't give the name of website here but it is still on the internet and grabing thounds of user evreyday..

Comment: Ebuyer was well-known for this a few years ago.

Comment: Yep. Somebody wanted me to help them build their own version of Craigslist that did this at first until they got "their own content." I explained that I was pretty sure this was illegal by digital millenium act standards but they didn't think it would be a big thing. I didn't take that contract.

Answer (score 19):

For me, the craziest (and quite possibly, funnest) was

> See this 10 million lines of code in (out-dated web technology)?  Write
>   a compiler to convert it to a working Asp.net site.

It never spit out a working version (of course, I tried to tell them it was impractical), but it was fun anyways.

Comment: Its nice of Joel S. to let his employees post about WASABI. ;-)

Comment: @Donny V. haha, I wish.  It was much, much, much crazier than that.  Dynamic inline sql used server side to generate mass quantities of dynamic server side code, leading to giant buckets of javascript and html with embedded server side code, that executed sql queries that...

Answer (score 19):

One major feature of an application our company developed was the ability to search large amounts of documents by the full-text of the document. A competitor made the following claim in a marketing presentation to one of our clients,

> Our search technology is superior because it doesn't just search the text of the documents,
>   it also searches the 'bits and bytes' of the actual file in binary form.

They gave a ridiculous example of how the decimal ascii repersentations of the words "boot" and "boat" were much less similar than the same words in binary form, when you compared the actual numeric digits in the representation. So searching based on the 1's and 0's more accurately reflected how similar those two words appeared visually, and thus improved recall.

Naturally I was tasked with researching this technique, which I assume was the result of a marketing guy completely misunderstanding a programmer somewhere, and drafting a response that we could include in our proposal.

Comment: I'm afraid I can think of a couple of search techniques that might (just) have made sense of the claim.

Answer (score 19):

Can you write a simple time entry and billing system for our new foreign office that uses a different language, currency and tax laws?

Comment: That's a good one :)

Answer (score 15):

Small team of programmers, boss wants us to do a ticket reservation system for a small airline (in a very short timeframe, of course). Team says:

-- as you can imagine, we will need some testers for this project

Boss says:

-- don't worry, learn from the car industry. They recall cars from time to time: users will do the testing.

Comment: Crash test comes to mind...

Comment: Sounds good, if airline has only 1 plane with 6 seats.

Answer (score 14):

I was a part of a mainframe support team that did shifts with other support teams in a data center. After the shift we would usually have a briefing with managers and the team of the next shift.  One day our new director showed up and asked the question: "Why average CPU load during your shift was only 72%, while previous shift shows near 95%? I think if we try real hard, we could eventually achieve 100% CPU load!"

Comment: Sounds like a 6 month project in Hawaii...

Answer (score 13):

About 12 years ago when I was in college I worked on a data modelling application for Windows.  The project was nearly complete after about 60,000 lines of Win32 code, you know, code targeting the Windows platform.  Then the client said the application also needs to run "on the web".  She had a hard time understanding how this one "minor little" requirements change could have such a big impact on the project.  I started over from scratch in Java but ended up quiting the project before it was ever finished.

Answer (score 13):

I was working on a big project in 1996 where we were scoring live sporting events.  This conversation happened:

Boss: Go out to the venue for the next event.

Me: What do you need me to do.

Boss: Be there just in case.

Me: Just in case what?

Boss: In case the tech lead loses it.  He's way too stressed out and I don't know what he 
might do.

Me: And if he loses it, what do you want me to do?

Boss: Just get him out of there so everyone else can continue working.  I don't care how you do it.

Answer (score 13):

First week - Have separate code base line for 2 different client (yes two copy of same code for 2 different client )

Second week (another boss) - No merge both codes and put IF - Else condition on every page

Answer (score 12):

Just last week someone asked me to make a simple change to an existing DLL (left pad a numerical value with leading zeros).

It was a COM DLL, originally coded in VB 6 - source code long since lost - which interfaced on one side with some external hardware (interface unknown) and whose functions were called from an Active X control on a web page (interface, again, unknown).

It only took me a week and I only slept overnight on the office floor twice.

But I got it done and it is live in the field as of yesterday - working.

Punchline - it was a government project, of course.

Comment: Did you bust out your trusty HEX editor?

Answer (score 12):

I was working on a web project in ASP.NET which was to replace an existing PHP solution. The PHP site wasn't bad, just a little outdated so the new project was to upgrade it using a new platform. The first thing to do was setup the new infrastructure by having IIS and MSSQL servers as well as a source control system.

A few weeks into creating the new project the project manager became unhappy with the deployment process which involved getting the latest version of the code, then deploying a build to the test environment. He felt that this was time consuming and that having people work on the same code base and having to merge their changes the wrong way to do things.

His solution was that we go back to the "old way" of doing things: writing PHP on the production server in real time with no source control or deployment strategy. This way you could have instant results and it didn't involve setting up source control or other servers. Needless to say things did not go well. :)

Comment: Ah, the wonders of PHBs: "Why don't you incompetent f***s have any way to know who changed what file when? Fix it!" Same PHB, another month later: "Which one of you incompetent f***ers broke the server again?" `svn log`..."uh, you did, Mr.PHB" In a meeting one day later: "That Subversion thing is just slowing you down, can't we get rid of that?"

Comment: I love source control and all its benefits as much as the next guy... but it just doesn't get your blood pumping as much as editing on the live production code.

Comment: @notJim  I love it and hate it at the same time.  One of my current jobs more or less requires it from time to time.  I ended up writing a "GoAway" script to display a down for maintinence message to everyone but me.

Comment: @WalterJ89-I was certainly joking! Some of the more stressful moments of my carreer have been when I've screwed something up on a live site!

Answer (score 12):

Wear khakis and a polo shirt.

Comment: "Wear a suit and a tie. No matter that the nearest client is three countries and 2000 km away from the dev team (and the clients have no intention of ever meeting the dev team), everyone else in the company wears a suit, as of tomorrow the dev team does likewise; violators will be fired. It Promotes Productivity!" (the Law of Unintended Consequences kicked in, as programmers analyzed the requirements and noted the lack of specification of the suit. A weirder collection of suits is yet to be seen; the Executive Order was cancelled the next day)

Comment: I am reading this in khakis and a polo shirt

Answer (score 12):

At the ISP I worked for back in the mid 1990s, the boss was friends with officers from our local police and sheriff stations. They were interested in catching securities fraud. So my boss hatches a plan:

Write a program to scan websites for evidence of securities fraud. That is:

- Start with IP address 0.0.0.1
- End at 255.255.255.254
- Scan every web page you find at each IP

This was back when pretty much every web server had a unique public-facing IP and virtual hosts didn't exist, so technically it was feasible. This was also back when a 1.5Mbps T-1 was really, really fast.

The problem? Even if we could scan ten IPs per second, the entire job would take almost 5,000 days to complete. Yep, had we gone through with such a program, it would be just now finishing its first scan of the entire Internet.

Comment: Probably, by this time you would have been encountered for threating internet security.

Comment: Wait, isn't Google doing the same thing ? They have catchy marketing names of course, but still...

Answer (score 11):

Well, this one time I bid on a freelance reverse engineering job, only to discover that they quite literally wanted me to be able to change the past.

Comment: This cries out for more detail.

Comment: They wanted me to be able to wait until winning lottery numbers were called, and then have their point of sale system report that they'd sold a winning ticket.  Which, at the time, I was really hurting for money, and the system wasn't in the US, and I'd have done that.  But it didn't report numbers in a cluster after the winning numbers were revealed.  It reported every time someone bought a ticket.  So I explained that if I had the power to do that, I'd be able to win the lottery at will, and wouldn't need their money.

Comment: Youch, not only impossible, but also illegal and unethical. I feel for you Torvaun...

Answer (score 11):

The last company that I worked for (and went bust) got a few bad reviews of the product.

So the decision was made by the upper management not to fix the problems but instead rebrand the product and relaunch it. Bugs included.

The other thing that made it really hard to stomach was the fact that the rebranding consisted of nothing more than a name change, which meant about 3 image swap-outs within the app and a few string replacements. The app looked the same, behaved the same, crashed the same.

Can't say I'm surprised the company didn't last.

Comment: Did you work for Microsoft?

Comment: Witty :P - except Microsoft aren't bust... yet.

Answer (score 8):

"Is there a way to make bar codes appear on the screen so that the user can scan them into the computer?"

Comment: funny... now there is actually

Comment: I sense some sort of infinite loop starting somewhere.

Comment: I've seen that done before.  It can make sense in certain contexts (plant control, etc) where there isn't a keyboard.

Comment: As Abraham Maslow almost said, when the only pointing device you have is a bar code reader, you tend to perceive all problems as bar codes.

Answer (score 8):

The question is in Bold, It needed a build up.

Client: "You need to write Automated tests using RFT against our popular Web application"

Me: "Okay, in which environment is it deployed?"

Client: "It is deployed in QA but you don't have permission to access it"

Me: "Yikes"

Client: **"Can you somehow finish writing the Automated tests without the application?"**

Me (in my mind): "I could, if I was superman or Chuck Norris"

Answer (score 8):

I was asked to write a report to show all sales and expenses for the future, a Nostradamus module for our accounts system :P He was very serious, it was not supposed to be a prediction but the actual values.

Comment: Tel them, that according to Nostradamus (at least believe by some people) world is going to end in 2012. So, reports can not display after 2012.

Comment: And development of the module will complete 2012-12-31.

Comment: Requirements: Batman's computer from the old TV series.

Answer (score 7):

We had a product release date pushed back a week so we could get the internal company footy tipping competition system running in time for the start of season...

Comment: You work in Sydney don't you? That sounds like something that goes on where i work too.

Comment: Melbourne, actually.

Answer (score 7):

Back in 2003 we were two developers and a designer that got this...

> I want you guys to do an imageserver application where you can just drag'n'drop images to upload them, without any extensions in the browser and it have to work on all platforms.

Truth be told we all looked at him and said something along the lines of

> If we knew how to do that, we wouldn't sit in these chairs in your company right now.

Comment: Thanks to HTML 5 this is now almost possible, Ah progress.

Comment: I like the "almost" possible :) but if we cranck the pessimist glasses it won't be ready until 2022 :P

Comment: @Neil Aitken, it's possible in *not* IE.

Answer (score 7):

My boss once insisted to me that Google's search results were all sorted by the highest bidder. He flatly refused to believe that Google tried to order its results by usefulness to the user. I tried to explain with simple logic that a system like that would result in the worst internet search engine imaginable to no avail.

In fact, he argued so vehemently that I'm pretty sure he'd just promised the client "the number one spot on Google if they were prepared to pay"... but didn't want to have to call back and look like an idiot.

*sigh*

Comment: I think you've got a typo: "...and reveal himself as an idiot." seems like the thing you wanted to say.

Comment: google seo please :)

Comment: That would require him to have to stop and read something he clearly didn't understand.

Answer (score 6):

Boss: I find it disgusting that you come in at 11am every day. I want you here at 8am, to help the data in-putters with any problems, and stay and help the dev team. When they go home at 7pm, you can start uploading changes to the sites.

Ofcourse, because of the ubersecurity for these sites (pharmaceutical company), we can only have one connection from our IP address to their servers, and I had 24 sites to upload. I was coming in at 11am because id be in the office till 3 or 4am uploading sites.

I left very shortly after.

Answer (score 5):

To learn a whole new programming language over the weekend.

Comment: Seems do-able to me.. at least to get the syntax. You could look up the methods and stuff.

Comment: This isn't terribly difficult.

Comment: I would expect any junior level programmer to be able to accomplish this.

Comment: While I agree, it's do-able and some people do it for fun, it's also the _WEEKEND_ :) supposedly, non-work time. Anyway, junior programmers usually have to do this because they might have had all their experience in language 1, then they get a job and suddenly have to use language 2. The problem arises when you have to make significant changes to a project within days of first encountering the central technology.

Comment: Not totally out of line, except for the part where he added, "on the weekend." That's _my_ time.

Comment: Well, if that new programming language is C++, make that 50 weekends plus the weeks in between. `:)`

Comment: It happen a lot in my organisation and I guess almost every where. They didn't mean be expert over the weekend. They just mean learn

Comment: Oh, hell, sure. Bill as an external consultant. Problem solved.

Comment: you just need a copy of "Teach yourself <language X> in 0 billable hours"

Comment: Depends on the language, and how many languages you already know -- and how much mastery of it they expect you to have on Monday morning.

Answer (score 5):

Can you add some post-processing so that the red part of this greyscale image is emphasised more than the green and blue parts?

Answer (score 5):

i swear to $Deity that a client once asked me to change (a+b)*0.5 to (a+b)/2

Comment: context? Depending on the language, those might actually be two different things.

Comment: ...or they might not. In Delphi, for example, the two are exactly equivalent.  In C, on the other hand, they're not.

Comment: Did he identify the location? give you the formula ? Or the result of the work was this?. I had to do a similar job but after a lot of debugging the problem was identified as similar to this.

Comment: some of y'all have only get 1/2 a sense of humor.  Or would that be 50% ;)

Answer (score 4):

Someone asked me to create a website which "copies what Google Local Search does and merges its data with other information coming from a database". I drew something in paper and the customer said it was ok; I charged him with 700 pounds (1000 US dollars) for a 5-days job.

I developed it in 3 nights and delivered it. I was proud of what I wrote until the customer said "It's almost ok. Why are you using the **googlemaps** rubygem? **I asked you to copy, not to use**"

PHB.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it would be a client requesting a Web App feature to "block print screen" while on the application, which makes absolutely no sense because in order to do that you have to either disable the clipboard, disable the key for the whole computer, but no, they wanted to disable the print screen key client-side (through javascript), which makes it even more senseless, on top of that no matter what you do as long as you are not affecting the whole computer functionality (which, you shouldn't), the user could work around it by just focusing another application and using print screen when the focus is on that other window.

Ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

I was working on a digital marketing website where we were selling DRM-protected Windows Media audio files; audio books for the most part. Microsoft pushed out some sort of required compliance update for all vendors to implement, assuming the vendors are deploying desktop client applications on end-user machines. The update required the application to check DLL versions on the client's machine to ensure they're up-to-date. My boss was literally drilling me for every conceivable way in which our website was allowed to check a web client's DLL file versions in his/her system folder, even to the point of suggesting we write our own Windows Media Player skin to do so.

Comment: Three words: signed Java applet. Done.

Answer (score 3):

Got a task that reduced down to the Halting Problem. I had just finished a Ph.D. in Recursion Theory. So funny!

We settled for a (cheesy) approximation.

Stephan

Comment: +1 for management not understanding the limitations of computation, it would have been more reasonable for them to ask for time travel

Answer (score 3):

At a credit bureau company, I was asked to replace a 100k C code service that checked fraud databases. Asynchronous multithreaded programming in Java replaced old C fork-join thechniques. The time frames were about 400-500 ms and 1-1.5 sec with stress. We managed to get 600 ms with ocassional peaks from databases' cache flushing.

1. My boss asked to configure it with 100 threads because "you never know" -- I did some research and testing and found 20 threads worked best.
2. The service depending on the one I wrote suddenly had trouble, my boss asked me to put a hardcoded timeout to cause more trouble, so we can assure I was not the faulty programmer.
3. My boss asked me to log every single operation to have control of all the process. That's ok I know. He asked me to go production with this version: Gigabyte logs every day.
   Two monts later I managed to change log to INFO from DEBUG and got 30% faster.
4. I was asked to go to five or six installations at 3 a.m. to replace the jar and change the name of the jar in the script that launched the service (the old C app was a mess and they were afraid I did the same thing).
5. The worst: I was forced to manage a team of 8, 5 were outsourcers, at the middle of the project. 1 of us never did anything, the outsources did a web app that 2 years after is not in production yet.

Comment: Let me guess.  You got blamed for the web app that isn't completed?

Answer (score 3):

I was asked by my TL to connect the phone line directly to USB (no MODEM type converter in between).

I tried to explain him that it is not possible technically (the connecting of phone to USB directly). but he didn't want to listen.

Then, I had to write him a 20 page document explaining that phone is analog while USB is digital so a converter is very much required. Then he dropped the idea altogether.

Comment: 20 pages? That seems like overkill.

Comment: @Nailer Depends on how sarcastic you want to be. In this situation I'd hapilly copy / paste entire academic documents explaining why he's asking for the impossible.

Comment: Can you share that document? I don't want to write anything like that if I need so.

Answer (score 3):

Client: When the power is lost, the electronic door lock should go to the failsafe position.

Me: Yes, of course. Just for clarification -- the failsafe position is "unlocked", right?

Client: Could you make it configurable in software whether the door is locked or unlocked when the power fails?

Me: (speechless).

Comment: Been there, heard that.  Sometimes they want it normally closed so no one can break-in.  Other times they want it normally opened so they don't die a horrible, burning death in case of fire.  Maybe next time we'll install two locks, just in case.

Comment: They want a persistent actuator in the lock for setting the fail-safe position. In the defence industry this wouldn't even be very remarkable.

Comment: Not funny as they probably meant can I make it configure it (while the power is up) and set what will happen the next time power goes out.  Just make that 'configuration' available thru software.

Answer (score 3):

I was asked to create a tenant blacklist website for landlords handling rental properties.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea to me, though they should call it a blocklist.  Some tenants habitually cause real physical damage to properties, never pay, and get kicked out of place after place.  How about calling it NotYourSpace.com or Evictus.com ?

Answer (score 3):

Coming late on that one but... I once worked as part of a QA team for a... let's say fairly big software project, which ultimately is part of a big telecommunications infrastructure.

Think big, as in really big, as in a few million people use it, to, well, communicate. Write, talk. Short distance and international stuff. That comes with billing as well to make sure it really matters.

The reason for me working with this team was that the technical launch date was approaching, and that they were quite late on the QA and defect identification front.

One morning I show up for our stand-up meeting, and the programme manager tells us that after a review meeting with the project's executives yesterday, they've decided that instead of having the software run on Windows 32 bits servers (which was decided like 2 years ago), they wanted it to run on HP/UX 64-bits machines.

No reason except that at the time 64 bits what becoming all the rate, so it must be better right? And totally justified. It was now only 2 weeks before the technical launch. Easy.

We fought this dearly (and with laughter).

Answer (score 2):

I was asked by my manager, a VP with connections to a support company in China, to transfer the support of my products to an external company.  When I tried to explain to him that this was not possible given our contractual obligations to our customers, his response was, "Of course we can do it - we did it at "xxx company" (his previous employer)  Never mind that the two companies made different classes of software, and had different licensing models.

Answer (score 2):

Make websites...

- without version control
- create them on the production server
- make changes using FTP direct to the production server
- start programming with no finalised idea of features or design

Comment: Been there, done that.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use an Object Database in an ERP system

2) Use an EVA Database in an ERP system

3) Craziest: Build a visual-based business rules system (a la Outlook Rules) to hand to our users (without a test harness to test the rules) and "throw it over the wall" at them. So instead of us writing programs for our users, we could just write a dumbed-down programming language for them and let them write their own apps.

Comment: Just noticed this answer.  I'm curious (don't know very much about either), what makes #1 crazy/silly etc?

Comment: The OODB's we tested ended up being about 40x to 100x slower than RDBMS for reporting and large batch transactions. It's just not designed for an ERP system. They can be great for certain things; db40 is awesome for small projects and embedded apps, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Q: "See this word here, how do I know if before that I should write 'a' or 'an'?"
A: Use "an" if the next word starts with a vowel
Q: "What's a vowel?"

Comment: It is not that simple (e.g. "a unique feature").

Comment: "an SQL database" or "a SQL database"?

Comment: @Michael, it depends how one pronounces SQL. Some Say S-Q-L, in which case it would be preceded with "an" because the phonetic S is "ess". Others pronounce it "Sequel" in which case it should be preceded by "a".

Comment: @Jasarien: well, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

To make a user manual for an automated process. 
The user manual basically say "Double click foo.exe and wait until it's done"

Comment: Having to deal with the end user of what I write I would say that is almost always necessary unfortunately

Comment: Probably you need another document to tel user to how to use that manual.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create and integrate a TCP Server into a Microsoft Access VBA Application.

It works kinda well, but it's probably the most insane piece of software I have ever written.

Answer (score 0):

I was once asked to make a field in a database "semi-compulsory" by a manager.

Just recently I was asked to develop a web application I had no prior knowledge of based on some JPEG mocks of what the website should look like that had been created by a design agency in another country who normally do print designs and have no idea about the web.

Comment: Please add details about the semi-compulsory field. I must know more!

Comment: Development based on JPEG out of a print studio? Pfffft! Regular work. Now, about, the semi-compulsory field... tell us more :)

Comment: Semi-compulsory isn't as crazy as it sounds; there's lots of cases where it's "required IF condition X is true". With the right DB constraints you can even enforce this... though it'd probably be better at a higher abstraction layer.

Comment: The semi-compulsory field came about because our database had to confirm to a national schema that defined the field should always have a value. I, naturally, made it non nullable in the DB. However, we also had to import data from various sources, and some of the providers complained that they didn't have any data for the field. Our project manager's solution was ingenious - make it "semi-compulsory".

Answer (score 0):

We work as a Scrum team and do our estimates for user stories in story points. When I looked at my second half goals for this year is was a requirement the the our story points must be within +/- 10 percent of the actual development hours spent on the story. For those involved in Agile you know story points are unitless and are based on a Fibonacci number sequence. I have yet to figure out how to make estimate match the actual how anyone could put such a requirement on the team.

Comment: Well, you could always put a higher estimate and then use the extra time browsing Programmers.SE :)